# Parsing JSON in javascript for multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

Should be quite a common answer but I haven't found it.

Using client-side javascript:

My client receives some JSON string:

```
response = 
[
 {"id1":"value1" , "time1":"valuetime1"},
 {"id2":"value2" , "time2":"valuetime2"}
]
```

I understand that I can simply parse the JSON string with this command:

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

But what is the next command to access each of the objects individually?
I would prefer to not use jQuery.

Comment: You may try obj1 = response[0];

Comment: In your example, initial `response` is an array, not a string. And `JSON.parse()` takes a string as an argument, it won't work on an array.

Comment: I didn't realise it would return a simple array because on attempting that I had another error that confused me. Thanks guys - answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In plain JavaScript, just use a simple for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
    console.log(response[i]); // Object with id and time
}
```

-or-

```
response.forEach(function(object){
    console.log(object); 
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PjePm/)

Comment: Won't simple `forEach()` be simpler than a simple `for` loop?

Comment: I've added that as well; I'm personally a believer that `.forEach` is a bit more confusing because of anonymous functions for early JS-ers.

Answer (score 0):

This JSON will become the appropriate JavaScript object. In this case, that is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which you can access the same way as you would any other JavaScript array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
  console.log(response[i]);
}
```